# Type Mismatch - Range and Number

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to check if a cell contains 8 or 9 digits in a row, but cannot figure out how to compare the two different types when using a variable. I suspect the error is in setting `numberId` as a Variant, and the operator to be comparing `###` formats resulting in a `Type mismatch` error:

```
Sub copyId()

Dim numberID As Variant, column As Range, pasteId As Range

Set column = Workbooks("Book4.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("C")
Set pasteId = Workbooks("Book5.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Columns("A")

For Each numberID In column
    If numberID Like "########" Or numberID Like "#########" Then numberID.Copy Destination:=pasteId
Next numberID

End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim numberID As Range`?

Comment: `numberID` would be a `Range` object here, so there's an implicit `numberID.[_Default]` member call that returns the `Range.Value`, and if that's a `Variant/Error` (e.g. `#N/A`, `#VALUE!`, `#REF!`, etc.) then comparing it to a string literal would throw a *Type Mismatch* error. Side note... it looks like you're iterating the *entire* column, which is likely to be *many* more rows than you really need to be looking at - consider only iterating rows that need to be iterated. It also looks like a 2nd match would overwrite the 1st: consider bailing out with `Exit For` (expand the `If` to a block).

Answer (score 0):

To match 8-9 numeric digits:

```
' Needs reference "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5"
Sub copyId()

    Dim numberID As Range, column As Range, pasteId As Range, i As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim rRegex As Object
    
    Set rRegex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    rRegex.Pattern = "[0-9]{8,9}"   ' 8 or 9 numbers
    
    Set column = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Columns("C")
    Set pasteId = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Columns("A")
    ' To limit results:
    LastRow = column.Cells(column.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        If rRegex.test(column.Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
            column.Cells(i, 1).Copy Destination:=pasteId.Cells(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! It runs without error, however it does not seem to be doing anything

Comment: I made some changes to match exactly 8 or 9 numeric digits in column C.